# How to add MailChimp API to HTML code

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm creating a landing page which I'd love to associate the submit button with MailChimp. 
Not sure how to do this though. Checked MailChimp and got their embedded HTML code to insert in the landing page code and then started to get confusing.

I'd love to keep the style of my landing page; how to add the MailChimp functionality keeping the landing page's style?

Below are the landing page code and the MailChimp code.

**LANDING PAGE'S CODE:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Veja Filme Online</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js">
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/APIModules_all.js">
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name ="keywords" content="" />    
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="shell">
        <div id="header-logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"    alt="logo"></a></div>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/leadbrite" data- send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="content">
    <div class="shell">

        <h2>Movies Direct oferece um software inovador que permite que você assista a <span>Qualquer Filme Online e Seriados Em HD Completos!</span> </br> Assista ao vídeo abaixo para ver nosso software em ação e <span>leve de presente</span> um filminho pra hoje!
        </h2>

        <div id="steps">
            <div id="step1">
                <h3 class="title">Passo #1 <span> Veja O Video </span></h3>

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Npz5pcBTFB8"><img src="images/veja_filmes_online.png" alt="juntos e misturados filme" width="500" height="286" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-749" /></a>

            </div>
            <div id="step2">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <h3 class="title">Passo #2</h3>
                    <p>Leve seu Filme<br />
                    <span>GRATUITO!</span></p>
                    <div id="book">
                        <img src="images/trapaca.jpg" alt="" width="186" height="269" />
                    </div>
                    <p><a id="button" class="popup-link" href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Quero Meu Filminho>></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <div class="shell">
        <p class="legal"><a href="#" target="_blank" >Legal Information</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>


<!-- PopUp -->
<div class="popup-container reveal-modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="popup" id="register_popup">
        <h1>Digite Seu Email</h1>       
        <p>Nós enviaremos seu filme agora mesmo!</p>    
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="email" value="Enter a Valid Email Here..." onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter a Valid Email Here...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter a Valid Email Here...') this.value='';" >
            </div>  
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar" class="submit" />         
        </form>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal"><img src="images/ico-close.png" /></a>
    </div>



</div>
<!-- END PopUp -->

<!-- Dynamic Like Button -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sUrl = window.location;
    document.getElementById('fb').setAttribute('https://www.facebook.com/pages/Movies-Direct-Veja-Filme-Online/313935295426774?focus_composer=true&ref_type=bookmark', sUrl);
</script>
<!-- END Dynamic Like Button -->
```

**MAILCHIMP CODE**

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://vejafilmeonline.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=4caa112c03695d368ee776414&amp;id=052f4c2450" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_4caa112c03695d368ee776414_052f4c2450" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```